# Is getLastRow() deprecated?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The documentation for spreadsheet.appendRow() says that it eliminates the need for getLastRow(). I'd actually like to use getLastRow() or something like it so I can append a block of data. Is it safe to use getLastRow(), or will it be depreciated? Unfortunately the docs don't link to the getLastRow() function and I can't figure out how to search the Google Apps API docs without pulling up a bunch of useless posts from their forum discussions.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#appendRow

Answer (score 4):

It is not deprecated. It is described under Spreadsheet -> Sheet -> getLastRow().

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet#getLastRow